# Client redirect through server: CORS error

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I try to redirect the user from my client trough my Express API to another page. The reason for this is once the user hits the POST 'auth/login' endpoint with success (and valid data) he/she will be redirected to the home page.
That gives me the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' (redirected from
> 'http://localhost:4000/auth/login') from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I assume this has something to do with handling CORS on the frontend, since my Express API is already using the following middleware:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

How would I be able to solve this blocking by the CORS policy (i.a. present a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header)?

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled on both the `http://localhost:4000/auth/login` server and the `http://localhost:3000` server?

Comment: In general if you get a message saying `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' … from origin 'http://localhost:3000'` (that is, where the request URL has the same origin as where he request is coming from), that indicates the browser has actually changed the origin to null — in which case limiting the allowed origin on the `http://localhost:3000` server to `http://localhost:3000` would not work, because that won’t match null. The value would instead need to be `*`. (The reason the  browser changes the origin to null is that the request was redirected across origins.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker I do have CORS currently only enabled on the server. How would I go over this if I want to enable this on the client as well?

Is it some specific header I can set in my axios request or do I have to install a lib and configure it?

Comment: For CORS, you can’t enable anything on the frontend side; instead it needs to be configured on the backend. So, in this case, whatever server backend runtime you’re using for the `http://localhost:3000/'` (e.g. node/express or whatever).

Comment: One thing I remain confused by about the error cited in the question is that the redirection from `http://localhost:4000/auth/login` back to your frontend `http://localhost:3000` looks like it might be the typical sort of redirection which happens in an OAuth flow or such — but if so, then what’s not typical is that you normally don’t want to be using ajax/XHR/fetch to make a request to an authentication/login endpoint. Instead, you want to be causing the user to actually be navigated to that auth/login endpoint — that is, by the user clicking a button or hyperlink which causes the navigation.

Comment: @sideshowbarker this is indeed part of an auth flow. I use passport.js (node/express) to handle various auth flows. Everything is working except for this 'local' (manual username/password) flow.

Essentially this is happening: users submits form => server handles the incoming request => when successful redirect to the client's homepage.

Comment: @Mainmehn did you manage to unstick yourself? I'm in the same situation

Comment: @CaioLuisGomes any updates? I'm having the same problem too :)